# How to stop GTK3 applications from hiding or shrinking the scrollbar?

Tags: gtk3

I notice that many GTK3 applications hide the scroll bar, or made it shrink so it is so small as to be barely visible. Is there any way to customize these settings so this behavior is not present? I need an easily see-able scroll bar at all times, assuming scroll is possible on that page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/775201/how-do-i-get-a-bigger-static-scrollbar-aka-normal-scrollbar

Comment: Or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014560/how-to-remove-overlay-scrollbars-in-ubuntu-17-10-and-18-04